# MathJax won't display MathML formula with a TeX annotation

Tags: javascript, mathjax, mathml

I use *MathJax* 3.2.0 to display MathML formulæ on web pages:

```html
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <mrow data-mjx-texclass="INNER">
    <mo data-mjx-texclass="OPEN">{</mo>
    <mtable columnspacing="1em" rowspacing="4pt">
      <mtr>
        <mtd>
          <mi>x</mi>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mi>y</mi>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
      <mtr>
        <mtd>
          <mi>z</mi>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mi>v</mi>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
    </mtable>
    <mo data-mjx-texclass="CLOSE">}</mo>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

And it is displayed by *MathJax* (not natively by the browser) as expected, with context menu, etc.

The MathML code for this formula is also generated from TeX by *MathJax* as a server-side *node.js* module.

However, after I try to inject (server-side, by editing the HTML) the original TeX code as a semantic annotation (see below), *MathJax* fails client-side: **Math output error**, with this floating tooltip: `this.variant[t] is undefined`. This happens only if the `<annotation>` tag is not empty.

I was able to find out that `this.variant[t]` was undefined in the functions `getVariant` and `getChar` and `t` was `""` in some cases and `undefined` in other.

```html
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <mrow data-mjx-texclass="INNER">
    <mo data-mjx-texclass="OPEN">{</mo>
    <mtable columnspacing="1em" rowspacing="4pt">
      <mtr>
        <mtd>
          <mi>x</mi>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mi>y</mi>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
      <mtr>
        <mtd>
          <mi>z</mi>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mi>v</mi>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
    </mtable>
    <mo data-mjx-texclass="CLOSE">}</mo>
  </mrow>
<semantics>
<annotation encoding="application/x-tex">\begin{Bmatrix} x &amp; y \\ z &amp; v \end{Bmatrix}</annotation>
</semantics>
</math>
```

*MathJax* is attached so:

```html
<script>
window.MathJax = {
    "loader":{"load":["ui\/safe"]},
    "options":{
        "skipHtmlTags":["script","noscript","style","textarea","pre","code","annotation","annotation-xml","tt","nowiki","kbd","syntaxhighlight"],
        "ignoreHtmlClass":["tex2jax_ignore","diff"],
        "menuOptions":{
            "settings":{
                "zoom":"DoubleClick",
                "semantics":true
            },
            "annotationTypes":{
                "TeX":["application\/x-tex"],
                "OpenMath":["OpenMath"]
            }
        },
        "enableEnrichment":true
    }
};
</script>
<script src="(skipped)/node_modules/mathjax-full/es5/mml-chtml.js?locale=ru"></script>
```

What could be wrong?

**UPD**: moving opening `<semantics>` just after `<math>`, i.e., wrapping the MathML code with `<semantics>` resolved the issue.

Comment: what if you move <semantics> opening tag above <mrow>?

Comment: @okzoomer, the same.

Comment: was using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Element/semantics) as a reference. I am not sure how you're "injecting" but make sure you are going through node.js to annotate not manually adding it to the html. also consider opening an issue on the mathjax github repo.

Comment: @okzoomer, I edit HTML server-side to add the annotation.

Comment: Yes, moving <semantics> opening tag before <mrow>, ie after <math> is what I was saying. The link I gave earlier has an example that illustrate this as well. Anyway glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Your `<semantics>` node is invalid.  The first child of `<semantics>` should be a presentation MathML node, not an `<annotation>` node.  That is, the first child of `<semantics>` should be the mathematics being annotated, and the second and subsequent nodes should be annotation nodes.  See the [MathML specifcation](https://www.w3.org/TR/MathML3/chapter5.html#mixing.elements.semantics) for details.  So

```xml
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
<semantics>
  <mrow data-mjx-texclass="INNER">
    <mo data-mjx-texclass="OPEN">{</mo>
    <mtable columnspacing="1em" rowspacing="4pt">
      <mtr>
        <mtd>
          <mi>x</mi>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mi>y</mi>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
      <mtr>
        <mtd>
          <mi>z</mi>
        </mtd>
        <mtd>
          <mi>v</mi>
        </mtd>
      </mtr>
    </mtable>
    <mo data-mjx-texclass="CLOSE">}</mo>
  </mrow>
  <annotation encoding="application/x-tex">\begin{Bmatrix} x &amp; y \\ z &amp; v \end{Bmatrix}</annotation>
</semantics>
</math>
```

is the correct way to annotate this math, as you point out in your update.

It appears that you are using MathJax to produce the original MathML.  If you are doing this in a browser using the MathJax contextual menu, note that there is an item in the "Show As" menu that you can select in order to include the original TeX as an annotation, so you don't have to do this yourself.  If you are using `mathjax-node`, you could configure `mathjax-node` to set that option as well.

Comment: Yes, I know, and noted that in my answer.  My answer tells you *why* that is the correct answer, and why your original is incorrect.